# SQL Server CASE 1 WHEN 1, WHERE 1=1 AND 1=1

Tags: sql-server

I inherited the following query from a previous application. I'm having a hard time understanding the "Case" in the "Select" and "Where" clause also.

```
SELECT J1.AC_CODE, J1.PERIOD, J1.JRNAL_NO, J1.DESCRIPTN, - J1.AMOUNT ,
                                                              J1.ANAL_T3,
                                                              CASE 1
                                                                  WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
                                                                  ELSE J1.ACCNT_CODE
                                                              END ,
                                                              J1.JRNAL_LINE
FROM dbo.JSource J1
WHERE 1=1
  AND 1=1
  AND NOT ('A' LIKE '%Z%'
           AND J1.JRNAL_SRCE IN ('B/F',
                                 'CLRDN')
           AND J1.JRNAL_NO = 0)
  AND CASE 1
          WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
          ELSE J1.AC_CODE
      END ='A'
  AND J1.AC_CODE='156320'
  AND J1.PERIOD BETWEEN 2014001 AND 2014012
  AND J1.ANAL_T3='ANAL001'
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

I'm not sure If I understand the following clauses correctly:

### 1st Clause:

```
CASE 1
 WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
 ELSE J1.AC_CODE
END
```

> I understood as: If column 1 is true, then choose literal A ortherwise choose J1.AC_CODE.

### 2nd clause:

```
WHERE 1=1
  AND 1=1
  AND NOT ('A' LIKE '%Z%'
           AND J1.JRNAL_SRCE IN ('B/F',
                                 'CLRDN')
           AND J1.JRNAL_NO = 0)
  AND CASE 1
          WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
          ELSE J1.AC_CODE
      END ='A'
  AND J1.AC_CODE='156320'
  AND J1.PERIOD BETWEEN 2014001 AND 2014012
  AND J1.ANAL_T3='ANAL001'
```

> I'm totally lost with this "Where" clause.

Can you help explain this query and write a better version for this whole query?
I'm running this query on SQL Server 2008 (R2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I understood as: If column 1 is true, then choose literal A ortherwise
>   choose J1.AC_CODE.

No, it is comparing the value `1` with the value `1` and if that is true the case returns an `A` and that is of course always true so the case statement will always return `A`.

Your where clause does not do anything at all.

```
1=1
  AND 1=1
```

will always be true and the case will always be true and `'A' LIKE '%Z%'` will always be false and that makes the entire `AND NOT 'A' LIKE '%Z%' ....` expression to always be true.

A simpler version of your query would look like this.

```
SELECT J1.AC_CODE,
       J1.PERIOD,
       J1.JRNAL_NO,
       J1.DESCRIPTN, 
       - J1.AMOUNT,
       J1.ANAL_T3,
       'A',
       J1.JRNAL_LINE
FROM dbo.JSource J1
WHERE J1.AC_CODE='156320' AND 
      J1.PERIOD BETWEEN 2014001 AND 2014012 AND
      J1.ANAL_T3='ANAL001'
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Comment: and what about these clauses -

WHERE J1.AC_CODE='156320'
AND J1.PERIOD BETWEEN 2014001 AND 2014012
AND J1.ANAL_T3='ANAL001'

Comment: @dimitar Those matter of course. I missed them since they where removed from the second version of the where clause.

Comment: This clause is still relevant to the query though:  NOT (J1.JRNAL_SRCE IN ('B/F','CLRDN') AND J1.JRNAL_NO = 0)

Comment: The complete query would be: SELECT J1.AC_CODE, 
J1.PERIOD, 
J1.JRNAL_NO, 
J1.DESCRIPTN, 
- J1.AMOUNT AS AMOUNT ,
J1.ANAL_T3,
J1.ACCNT_CODE,
J1.JRNAL_LINE
FROM dbo.JSource J1
WHERE NOT (J1.JRNAL_SRCE IN ('B/F',
                                 'CLRDN')
                   AND J1.JRNAL_NO = 0)

  AND J1.AC_CODE='156320'
  AND J1.PERIOD BETWEEN 2014001 AND 2014012
  AND J1.ANAL_T3='ANAL001'
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Comment: @Narazana It is only relevant if you remove `'A' LIKE '%Z%'`.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the history of this query, I am guessing that this was written with testing/debugging in mind and some of that code has been left in place. The case statement in the select line could (and I repeat could as this is my guess from looking at the query) have had other with clauses during creation of the query used for testing and these would have been switched between by changing the value after the CASE (example SELECT ..... CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN 'A' WHEN 2 THEN 'some value' WHEN 3 'some other value'  ELSE J1.ACCNT_CODE).

As for the where 1 = 1, I have seen this used during query creation/testing - mainly because it means each of the true conditions can easily be commented/uncommented or cut & pasted as the first where condition is always true. I've not seen AND 1 = 1 before. Not sure what that line was intended for, but I'd still think came about from testing/debugging and was not taken out the query.

Comment: Apologies I could not post as comment to Mikael's correct answer as I'm new to this site so don't have the required 50 reputation to post comments. I just thought I could give a possible reason those unneeded lines were there.